# How can I use two or more tables?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I have Two tables, i am fetching the data by left-join but it taking too much time to pull the datas into my dataTable as my database is very big. Is there any other option? Kindly help please.

```
    $allPolicyWithOrganization = $allPolicyWithOrganization
        ->select('policies.*', 
                 'leads.lead_id', 
                 'leads.agent', 
                 'leads.referrer_id', 
                 'leads.vendor_id', 
                 'leads.deleted_at'
                )
        //->where('policies.status', '!=', 1)
        ->leftJoin('leads', 'policies.lead_id', '=', 'leads.lead_id');
```

I have policy table and lead table..i want to pull the all  data from the tables..it taking so much time

Comment: Apply indexing on the fields which you are using in where condition and for joining

Answer (score 0):

You should use views of database, and create index of those column where you have set filter criteria. It will fetch record rapidly. Try out this solution your problem will be solve. #Abir Adak

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using indexes in the fields you need to filter, have you tried using the cache?

```
Schema::table('leads', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index(['lead_id', 
                   'agent', 
                   'referrer_id', 
                   'vendor_id', 
                   'deleted_at'
                   ]);
});
```

and use cache (in my case Redis)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
```

```
$allPolicyWithOrganization = Cache::tags('policies')
         ->rememberForever('all.policies.with.organization', function () {
            return $allPolicyWithOrganization
                   ->select('policies.*', 
                            'leads.lead_id', 
                            'leads.agent', 
                            'leads.referrer_id', 
                            'leads.vendor_id', 
                            'leads.deleted_at'
                           )
            //->where('policies.status', '!=', 1)
            ->leftJoin('leads', 'policies.lead_id', '=', 'leads.lead_id');
         });
```

Remember to clear the cache when there are changes in the affected tables.

```
Cache::forget('all.policies.with.organization');
```

or by tag

```
Cache::tags('policies')->flush();
```

[Cache Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache)